# Azure IoT hub publisher TIMEOUTs when sending data in Python2.7

Tags: python, azure, iot

I am trying to send some data to a Azure IoT hub(AIH) server from a BananaPi M3 running a Raspbian OS. To do this, I builded the Python 2.7 library for AIH and got the valid library named iothub_client.so. To test if the lib is ok I just tried to do a simple import like: from iothub_client import * and it worked.

So, After this I setup the connection string as described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/doc/get_started/python-run-sample.md) and ran the script from the [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/python/device/samples/iothub_client_sample.py). 
This is the output of the app:

```
> >>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
IoT Hub for Python SDK Version: 1.0.13
Starting the IoT Hub Python sample...
    Protocol MQTT
    Connection string=HostName=************************;DeviceId=*************;SharedAccessKey=*************************
IoTHubClient sending 5 messages
IoTHubClient.send_event_async accepted message [0] for transmission to IoT Hub.
IoTHubClient.send_event_async accepted message [1] for transmission to IoT Hub.
IoTHubClient.send_event_async accepted message [2] for transmission to IoT Hub.
IoTHubClient.send_event_async accepted message [3] for transmission to IoT Hub.
IoTHubClient.send_event_async accepted message [4] for transmission to IoT Hub.
Confirmation[0] received for message with result = MESSAGE_TIMEOUT
    message_id: message_0
    correlation_id: correlation_0
    Properties: {'Property': 'PropMsg_0'}
    Total calls confirmed: 1
Confirmation[1] received for message with result = MESSAGE_TIMEOUT
    message_id: message_1
    correlation_id: correlation_1
    Properties: {'Property': 'PropMsg_1'}
    Total calls confirmed: 2
Confirmation[2] received for message with result = MESSAGE_TIMEOUT
    message_id: message_2
    correlation_id: correlation_2
    Properties: {'Property': 'PropMsg_2'}
    Total calls confirmed: 3
Confirmation[3] received for message with result = MESSAGE_TIMEOUT
    message_id: message_3
    correlation_id: correlation_3
    Properties: {'Property': 'PropMsg_3'}
    Total calls confirmed: 4
Confirmation[4] received for message with result = MESSAGE_TIMEOUT
    message_id: message_4
     correlation_id: correlation_4IoTHubClient sending 5 messages
```

Does anybody have an idea why I get all TIMEOUT messages?

Thank you

Comment: Check your network connection. Also, use "Device Explorer" to monitor the message to IoT Hub.

Comment: I have verified the sample to work with Ubuntu14.04 running on Virtualbox.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the protocol to `HTTP`
example:

```
PROTOCOL = IoTHubTransportProvider.HTTP
```